# Imageview not matching the width of Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout in which a linearlayout contains imageview as its direct child. I want to fit the width of this imageview so that it spans horizontally to match the size of the parent which will take the width of the whole screen.

How can I do that? This is what i've done so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/policemen_salute"
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            />



    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: ok and what is the problem?

Comment: It doesnt stretch vertically.

Comment: i mean horizontally.

Comment: show us what it looks like

Comment: ok, ill screen capture it.

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture. I want to stretch it horizontally not vertically.

Comment: it looks like that because that is what your image is. you need to set the scale type like the answers suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the 'scaletype' attribute:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/policemen_salute"
        android:id="@+id/banner"/>
```

See
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: will try this. I'll get back to you.

Comment: it works, thanks :3. Will mark this as the answer. Though many same answers were posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use android Scaletype Property .

`android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Then set android adjustviewbounds true from XML .Try this way I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `scaleType` to scale correctly the image.
try your ImageView like this:

`<ImageView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      android:src="@drawable/policemen_salute"
      android:id="@+id/banner"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to scale your image, you might want to add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

(Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly) 
to your ImageView

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/policemen_salute"
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            />
```